# Why can't you change anchor points and what is the point?- box2d

Tags: box2d

I have noticed that you cannot change the anchor points of box2d objects from their original 0.5, 0.5, so I would like to ask you:
Why is this option not available and what is the point of having the anchor points always at the center, like why did the developers choose to do so?

Thanks, your time is much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you getting 0.5 from? Please name the classes, methods and/or functions you're getting this value from.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing Box2D stuff with something else, like cocos2d-iphone stuff? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025576/change-box2d-anchor-point?rq=1