# How is anchorPoint in Cocos2d determined for non-rectangular PNGs?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I know this is a basic question, but I couldn't find a definitive answer online. I've read [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808981/moving-a-stick-figure-anchorpoints-animation-or-something-else/7810180#7810180) to a question on anchorPoints in general, but the user starts his answer with:

> Let's assume your rectangular sprite image

I understand very clearly in this case where the default anchor point (0.5f, 0.5f) will be. My question is: *If you have an irregularly shaped PNG image (i.e., non-rectangular), how exactly is the anchorPoint determined?*

My strong hunch is that the "width" and "height" in this case are taken to be equal to those of the **smallest bounding rectangle**. This is illustrated below:

[image: anchorPoint middle of bounding rectangle]

However, there are other possibilities to calculate the center point of a non-rectangular image, such as using the "**center of mass**" of the image:

[image: anchorPoint using center of mass]

Can someone either confirm or refute my hunch? Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as non-rectangular PNG, it is just a rectangular PNG with some transparency. So the anchor point of the sprite will be always just in the center of that image (unless you change it).

Answer (score 0):

The anchor point is always calculated based on the content size of a node. Per default a `CCSprite` has a content size of the image that you used as a texture, so the image size of the texture is the basis of the calculation.

The content of the image is not relevant only the dimensions influence the content size.